# Taking photo with custom name

Tags: product-photography, software-recommendation, bulk-load

I am making a school management system, which allows students to be registered on the system along side with their photo. Every one know the pain of uploading single photo of 500 students.. 
So I wonder if I first register all the students and then I give every student an unique ID, after then I Take photos according to their ID

EXAMPLE
A student with an ID of 001, he will be the first to be captured, and that program will rename first photo with STD001,

A student with an ID of 002,  will be the second to be captured, and that program will rename second photo with STD002,

A student with an ID of 003,  will be the third to be captured, and that program will rename third photo with STD003,

A student with an ID of 300,  will be the 300th to be captured, and that program will rename three hundredth photo with STD300,

So i can upload all photos at once and the system will know where to upload to each student

Comment: What's your actual question here? It seems much more like a programming question than a photography one.

Comment: @PhilipKendall this is not programming one. I want to know the name of the software which can enable me to take picture in series, like picture one to be IMG001, IMG002, IMG003, IMG004

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can typically reset the counter used by the computer to construct file names from within your camera's setup menu.  There is typically no way to change the foot file prefix (e.g. change IMG to STD) but that's not really needed here.

Comment: @StephenG that prefix does not matter, all I need is 001,002,003,004...

Comment: @PhilipKendall this is not software comparison like, which one is best... It is the name of the software that I need..

Comment: This is not a photography question. You are simply asking in the wrong place.

Comment: This is equally off-topic on Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic at Software Recommendations if tidied up.

Comment: So What should i do to get that done @PhilipKendall

Comment: However you do it, this just begs for a mistake to be made, someone to be out of sequence or missing, and the whole scheme get off.  Consider a failsafe, like having their student ID in a small holder that's in frame (but could be cropped out easily) so you can double check the result no matter how you name the files.  Test to be sure you have the resolution to read their ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cameras natively name the photos in consecutive numbers. You could simply trim the prefix and replace it with another or simply adjust your program to pull IMG_0003 instead of STD003.

There are a lot of batch renaming programs to do this. On windows, Irfan View (and you can resample your image too) or AF5 Rename your files.

But an automated process is probably a bad idea.

Take a look at this question: [How do I keep track of many, many clients in a single shoot (like a school portrait day)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70228/how-do-i-keep-track-of-many-many-clients-in-a-single-shoot-like-a-school-portr)

You potentially will have a mess if one photo is misfired.

You need some kind of Visual-check/On-site-renaming/ to confirm the match.